# change column name Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have this table:

```
class CreateShoes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :shoes do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.boolean :leather
      t.integer :season

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

the 'season' column should be called 'season_id'. I know that I have to write 't.rename :season, :season_id' as explained in http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#column-modifiers but I don't manage to find the right syntax. Should it be?

```
class CreateShoes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :shoes do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.boolean :leather
      t.integer :season

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    change_table :products do |t|
      t.rename :season, :season_id
    end

  end
end
```

Doesn't work. Anything I have to do in the Mac console? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you renaming it in the same migration? Either rollback and fix it in the `create_table`, or create a new migration. You can also just write `rename_column :shoes, :season, :season_id` instead of putting it in a block.

Comment: I don't quite know what I doing. learning :) forgot to add that the table has data in it. create new migration means a new 'def change'? thx

Comment: It means a new migration that has its own `change` method.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Run in your console:

```
$ rails g migration rename_season_to_season_id
```

Now file `db/migrate/TIMESTAMP_rename_season_to_season_id.rb` contains following:

```
class RenameSeasonToSeasonId < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  end
end
```

Modify it as follows:

```
class RenameSeasonToSeasonId < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :shoes, :season, :season_id
  end
end
```

Then run `$ rake db:migrate` in console.

Answer (score 5):

Either fix your migration and do

```
rake db:rollback db:migrate
```

or make another migration like so:

```
rename_column :shoes, :season, :season_id if column_exists?(:shoes, :season) && !column_exists?(:shoes, :season_id)
```

and then do

```
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to rename column in table than you example migration is not making sense :)... Instead of this

```
class CreateShoes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :shoes do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.boolean :leather
      t.integer :season

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    change_table :products do |t|
      t.rename :season, :season_id
    end

  end
end
```

You just need table change migration, like this(Rails will take care rollback for your):

```
class RenameSessionColumnInsideShoes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :products do |t|
      t.rename :season, :season_id
    end
  end
end
```

`rename` method on table object in rails is valid method, as you can see in Rails source code

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb#L582

Answer (score 1):

If your branch has been pushed to production then one probably needs to add the new migration by running the following command:

`rails g migration RenameSeasonColumnNameToShoes`

and if it hasn't been pushed to production or you have to currently make changes to your branch only, then do:

`bundle exec rake db:rollback`

Then make changes to your migration file inside `/db/migrate/<your_migration_file_name>`

Then in your migration file, using `rename_column` do as follows:

```
class RenameSeasonColumnNameToShoes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
      rename_column :shoes, :season, :season_id
  end
end
```

and then do

`bundle exec rake db:migrate db:test:prepare`