# Rails : Associating a record with a user who did not create that record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user model and a patient model. Patients are not users of the application. Users are essentially staff members who are creating patient records. In some situations, the user who creates the patient's record is also that patient's physician. In other cases, the patient's physician could be a separate user.

I want to save the user id of the patient's physician to the patient model rather than the user who happened to create the patient. The implementation I am imagining is that I will have a dropdown field in the form for the user to select the patient's physician, including the option to select themselves. How can I do this? Am I even thinking about this the right way?  Here is my current implementation:

```
class Patient < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user

class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :patients
```

Patients Controller

class PatientsController < ApplicationController

```
def new
    @patient = current_user.patients.build
end

def create
    @patient = current_user.patients.build(patient_params)
    if @patient.save
        flash[:success] = "Patient Created!"
        redirect_to new_referral_request_path(patient_id: @patient.id)
    else
        Rails.logger.info(@patient.errors.inspect)
        render 'patients/new'
end
end

private

def patient_params
    params.require(:patient).permit(:age, :user_id, insurance_ids: [], gender_ids: [], concern_ids: [], race_ids: [])

end
end
```

patient's schema:

```
  create_table "patients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "age"
    t.string   "user_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_patients_on_user_id"
  end
```

I have two roles: one for staff and one for clinician. Staff users would be the ones creating patients. A staff user who creates a patient record may or may not be that particular patient's physician.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  self.inheritance_column = :role
  enum role: { Staff: 0, Clinician: 1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `physician` relation to `Patient` model:

```
class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :physician, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Then modify schema:

```
create_table "patients", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer  "age"
  t.string   "user_id"
  t.integer  "physician_id"
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_patients_on_user_id"
  t.index ["physician_id"], name: "index_patients_on_physician_id"
end
```

Hint: use `integer` for your `id`s fields, if your ids are numeric.

(Of course, its better to do this through migration, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796492/change-column-name-rails/34796826#34796826) if you don't know how).

Then permit `physician_id` in `params`:

```
def patient_params
  params.require(:patient).permit(:age, :user_id, :physician_id, insurance_ids: [], gender_ids: [], concern_ids: [], race_ids: [])
end
```

And finally add dropdown list in the form:

```
<%= form_for(@patient) do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :physician_id, User.all.map { |u| [u.name, u.id] } %>
  ...other fields...
<% end %>
```

Now you can call both `patient.user` and `patient.physician` (which can be equal).

Comment: Hi Inpego - I already have roles implemented through enums with single table inheritance for Staff and Clinician. The issue is that the staff user who creates the patient's record may or may not be that patient's physician. How can I implement your suggestion with that setup?

Comment: Please create a new question with more detailed description and notify me.